# Is $f(x):=(x-a)^n g(x)$ $n$ times differentiable at $a$, for any $g$ continuous at $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, finite-differences

This is a try to fill the holes in [this previous exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096924/show-that-f-have-a-zero-of-m-ge-n-multiplicity-iff-exists-some-g-such-that).

Let $f$ defined as $f(x):=(x-a)^n g(x)$, for some $g$ continuous in a neighborhood of $a$, we can say that $f$ is $n$ times differentiable at $a$?

If we define the quotient difference operator

$$\Delta^n_h f(x):=\frac1{h^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f(x+(n-k)h)(-1)^k$$

then if $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $a$ and if Im not wrong we can write

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\Delta^n_h f(a)=f^{(n)}(a)$$

For the case of the title this reduces to

$$\begin{align}f^{(n)}(a)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{h^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k((n-k)h)^ng(a+(n-k)h)\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(n-k)^ng(a+(n-k)h)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(n-k)^ng(a)\end{align}$$

and for derivatives for $j\le n$ we have that $f^{(j)}(a)=0$.

It is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Not quite - your limit formula is true if we know that the limit in question exists, but it doesn't guarantee that the derivative exists a priori.

Comment: @πr8 thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer that I was searching for.

Comment: Typographical note: The AMS `align*` environment can be used to typeset wide display math so the "$=$"'s line up. If the backquote construction permits preformatted text, for example: `\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= g(x) \\
  &= h(x).
\end{align*}` (It doesn't, but perhaps the resulting hash is legible enough to be helpful anyway....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning is *not* correct. The equality
$$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\Delta_h^nf(a)=f^{(n)}(a)$$
is true, *provided that the RHS exists*. However, just because the limit on the LHS exist, it doesn't follow the RHS exists. Indeed, the statement in the question is *false*. This is because $f(x)$ can oscillate very rapidly in the neighbourhood of $a$, which would make the first derivative be discontinuous at $a$. To be precise, consider for example 
$$g(x)=x\sin x^{-2}\text{ for }x\neq 0,\\g(0)=0$$ (check it's continuous) and $$f(x)=x^2g(x)=x^3\sin x^{-2}.$$

We then find
$$f'(x)=3x^2\sin x^{-2}-2\cos x^{-2},\\
f'(0)=0,$$
which is discontinuous at zero, hence $f$ is not twice differentiable.

For general $n$, you can similarly take $f(x)=x^{n+1}\sin x^{-n}$.

Comment: Or let $g$ be nowhere differentiable, then $(x-a)^n g(x)$ is (for $n \geqslant 1$) differentiable at $a$, but nowhere else.

Comment: Yup, this looks better than my thing :-)

Comment: @DanielFischer That works as well, and is probably quite easier to think of.